# What name this event bottom scroll android app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, material-design

I am new in android, When we scroll the activity down to the end there is a highlight effect as you see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGxck.jpg) , What's it called and how can I achieve this?

I use cordova for dev android app.

thanks

Comment: It's called EdgeEffect.  It is applied to native Android app scrolling components only, not for HTML based pages.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html

Comment: Ok thank you @DougStevenson yeah this effect not for html. I hope this effect can run in cordova